# Chrome reports UDP port blocked but netcat can connect

Tags: networking, google-chrome, port, udp

I am using Chrome browser 84.0.4147.89 (64-bit) and when I run the Chrome `Connectivity Diagnostics` I get the following error log for UDP port 19302-19309.

> SUMMARY
> Test Name: Hangouts Connectivity Test
> Test ID: 12
> Test result: Potential problem detected
>
> CRITERIA
> Hangouts blocked test returns a no problem verdict if: (1) a connection can be established to stun.l.google.com on any UDP port from 19302 to 19309 (2) A TCP connection can be established to apis.google.com, clients6.google.com, plus.google.com, and talkgadget.google.com
> Hangouts blocked test returns a problem verdict if: (1) all UDP destination ports from 19302 to 19309 are blocked for stun.l.google.com (2) A TCP connection to any of the following hosts fails on port 443: apis.google.com, clients6.google.com, plus.google.com, talkgadget.google.com
>
> SUPPORT DETAILS
> https://support.google.com/a/answer/1279090
>
> DETAILS
> Tue Jul 21 2020 11:33:04 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time) - Setting UDP timeout length (msec): 10000
> Tue Jul 21 2020 11:33:04 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time) - Creating a UDP socket, number / host / port: 30 / stun.l.google.com / 19302
> Tue Jul 21 2020 11:33:04 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time) - Preparing to send UDP socket data with size (bytes): 20
> Tue Jul 21 2020 11:33:04 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time) - Successfully sent data with size (bytes): 20
> Tue Jul 21 2020 11:33:14 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time) - UDP connection failed and is blocked on destination port 19302
> Tue Jul 21 2020 11:33:14 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time) - Setting UDP timeout length (msec): 10000
> Tue Jul 21 2020 11:33:14 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time) - Creating a UDP socket, number / host / port: 31 / stun.l.google.com / 19303
> Tue Jul 21 2020 11:33:14 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time) - Preparing to send UDP socket data with size (bytes): 20
> Tue Jul 21 2020 11:33:14 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time) - Successfully sent data with size (bytes): 20
> Tue Jul 21 2020 11:33:24 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time) - UDP connection failed and is blocked on destination port 19303
> Tue Jul 21 2020 11:33:24 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time) - Setting UDP timeout length (msec): 10000
> Tue Jul 21 2020 11:33:24 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time) - Creating a UDP socket, number / host / port: 32 / stun.l.google.com / 19304
> Tue Jul 21 2020 11:33:24 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time) - Preparing to send UDP socket data with size (bytes): 20
> Tue Jul 21 2020 11:33:24 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time) - Successfully sent data with size (bytes): 20
> Tue Jul 21 2020 11:33:34 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time) - UDP connection failed and is blocked on destination port 19304
> Tue Jul 21 2020 11:33:34 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time) - Setting UDP timeout length (msec): 10000
> Tue Jul 21 2020 11:33:34 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time) - Creating a UDP socket, number / host / port: 33 / stun.l.google.com / 19305
> Tue Jul 21 2020 11:33:34 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time) - Preparing to send UDP socket data with size (bytes): 20
> Tue Jul 21 2020 11:33:34 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time) - Successfully sent data with size (bytes): 20
> Tue Jul 21 2020 11:33:44 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time) - UDP connection failed and is blocked on destination port 19305
> Tue Jul 21 2020 11:33:44 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time) - Setting UDP timeout length (msec): 10000
> Tue Jul 21 2020 11:33:44 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time) - Creating a UDP socket, number / host / port: 34 / stun.l.google.com / 19306
> Tue Jul 21 2020 11:33:44 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time) - Preparing to send UDP socket data with size (bytes): 20
> Tue Jul 21 2020 11:33:44 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time) - Successfully sent data with size (bytes): 20
> Tue Jul 21 2020 11:33:54 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time) - UDP connection failed and is blocked on destination port 19306
> Tue Jul 21 2020 11:33:54 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time) - Setting UDP timeout length (msec): 10000
> Tue Jul 21 2020 11:33:54 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time) - Creating a UDP socket, number / host / port: 35 / stun.l.google.com / 19307
> Tue Jul 21 2020 11:33:54 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time) - Preparing to send UDP socket data with size (bytes): 20
> Tue Jul 21 2020 11:33:54 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time) - Successfully sent data with size (bytes): 20
> Tue Jul 21 2020 11:34:04 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time) - UDP connection failed and is blocked on destination port 19307
> Tue Jul 21 2020 11:34:04 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time) - Setting UDP timeout length (msec): 10000
> Tue Jul 21 2020 11:34:04 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time) - Creating a UDP socket, number / host / port: 36 / stun.l.google.com / 19308
> Tue Jul 21 2020 11:34:04 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time) - Preparing to send UDP socket data with size (bytes): 20
> Tue Jul 21 2020 11:34:04 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time) - Successfully sent data with size (bytes): 20
> Tue Jul 21 2020 11:34:14 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time) - UDP connection failed and is blocked on destination port 19308
> Tue Jul 21 2020 11:34:14 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time) - Setting UDP timeout length (msec): 10000
> Tue Jul 21 2020 11:34:14 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time) - Creating a UDP socket, number / host / port: 37 / stun.l.google.com / 19309
> Tue Jul 21 2020 11:34:14 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time) - Preparing to send UDP socket data with size (bytes): 20
> Tue Jul 21 2020 11:34:14 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time) - Successfully sent data with size (bytes): 20
> Tue Jul 21 2020 11:34:24 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time) - UDP connection failed and is blocked on destination port 19309
> Tue Jul 21 2020 11:34:24 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time) - Setting TCP timeout length (msec): 10000
> Tue Jul 21 2020 11:34:24 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time) - Creating a TCP socket, number / host / port: 38 / stun.l.google.com / 443
> Tue Jul 21 2020 11:34:24 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time) - TCP connection established with host / port / status code: stun.l.google.com / 443 / 0
> Tue Jul 21 2020 11:34:24 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time) - TCP connection succeeded on port 443 for host 443
> Tue Jul 21 2020 11:34:24 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time) - Setting TCP timeout length (msec): 10000
> Tue Jul 21 2020 11:34:24 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time) - Creating a TCP socket, number / host / port: 39 / apis.google.com / 443
> Tue Jul 21 2020 11:34:24 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time) - TCP connection established with host / port / status code: apis.google.com / 443 / 0
> Tue Jul 21 2020 11:34:24 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time) - Setting TCP timeout length (msec): 10000
> Tue Jul 21 2020 11:34:24 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time) - Creating a TCP socket, number / host / port: 40 / talkgadget.google.com / 443
> Tue Jul 21 2020 11:34:24 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time) - TCP connection established with host / port / status code: talkgadget.google.com / 443 / 0
> Tue Jul 21 2020 11:34:24 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time) - Setting TCP timeout length (msec): 10000
> Tue Jul 21 2020 11:34:24 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time) - Creating a TCP socket, number / host / port: 41 / clients6.google.com / 443
> Tue Jul 21 2020 11:34:24 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time) - TCP connection established with host / port / status code: clients6.google.com / 443 / 0
> Tue Jul 21 2020 11:34:24 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time) - Setting TCP timeout length (msec): 10000
> Tue Jul 21 2020 11:34:24 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time) - Creating a TCP socket, number / host / port: 42 / hangouts.google.com / 443
> Tue Jul 21 2020 11:34:24 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time) - TCP connection established with host / port / status code: hangouts.google.com / 443 / 0

But when I do `netcat` it tells me the ports are open and fine:

> $ nc -v -u -z -w 3 stun.l.google.com 19302-19309
> Connection to stun.l.google.com 19302 port [udp/*] succeeded!
> Connection to stun.l.google.com 19303 port [udp/*] succeeded!
> Connection to stun.l.google.com 19304 port [udp/*] succeeded!
> Connection to stun.l.google.com 19305 port [udp/*] succeeded!
> Connection to stun.l.google.com 19306 port [udp/*] succeeded!
> Connection to stun.l.google.com 19307 port [udp/*] succeeded!
> Connection to stun.l.google.com 19308 port [udp/*] succeeded!
> Connection to stun.l.google.com 19309 port [udp/*] succeeded!

If I use a VPN then I don't have any issues with blocked ports. So it is something on my local network that is causing this issue.

I have setup port forwarding for these ports and I have also tried disabling `chrome://flags/#same-site-by-default-cookies`, but nothing has resolved the issue.

What is keeping `Connectivity Diagnostics` from connecting to these UDP ports?

Comment: netcat here will "succeed" if it doesn't receive back an ICMP destination port unreachable. Not receiving back anything "succeeds" after the timeout... not! It's just failing at testing UDP (it actually sent a data packet in UDP mode with the -z (zero) option). Don't test with netcat. try with a stun related tool.

Comment: You're right, using `stun` shows that the port is blocked